# Who are the current "working members" of the UK Royal Family?

Tags: united-kingdom, royal-family

In relation to [recent news](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-51163865) that

> "The Sussexes will not use their HRH titles as they are no longer working members of the Royal Family."

(HRH = "His/Her Royal Highness".) 
Is there an official list of the "working members" of the UK Royal Family?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## There isn’t an official list.

But here’s the [list of royals who undertook official engagements](https://www.express.co.uk/news/royal/1175378/royal-news-hardest-working-royal-family-meghan-markle-camilla-kate-middleton) in the previous year (2019), a good gauge of the list of “working royals”:

> 1. Princess Anne: 137
> 2. Prince Charles: 131
> 3. Queen Elizabeth II: 122
> 4. Prince Andrew: 105
> 5. Prince Edward: 78
> 6. The Duke of Kent: 76
> 7. Prince Harry: 69
> 8. Camilla, the Duchess of Cornwall: 69
> 9. The Duke of Gloucester: 66
> 10. Prince William: 66
> 11. Sophie, Countess of Wessex: 60
> 12. Kate Middleton: 41
> 13. Princess Alexandra: 32
> 14. The Duchess of Gloucester: 30
> 15. Meghan Markle: 25

In addition to the Sussexes stepping down as working royals, Prince Andrew has also [stood down from public duties](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/11/20/world/europe/prince-andrew-quits-epstein.html).

Comment: +1 but both articles seem to cite [the same source](https://royalcentral.co.uk/features/insight/who-are-the-senior-royals-118652/) (Royal Central) which is actually less definitive in its proclamations. For example, it says: "Then there is the matter of who does the most work? This system would put The Queen and Princess Anne at the top, and then people such as the Duke of Gloucester higher than the Duke of Cambridge, despite their extremely differing roles. This system is somewhat flawed from the start as workloads fluctuate in The Royal Family, and it is no measure of someone’s seniority."

Comment: @Fizz I see your point, I’ve updated my answer for a more representative list.